# Fragment glitches in Blender when camera's far away from object

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, compositing-nodes, blender-internal-render-engine

Another problem has risen about my Earth. When the camera starts to go away from the Earth, these weird fragments appear. I've figured out that it's the Earth map coming through the clouds and atmosphere but only at a distance. They're far apart enough and I don't know if it's a setting that causes this.

[image]

Comment: Looks like Z fighting to me

Comment: I've managed to fix it now, just moved the near clipping distance of my camera from 0.001 to 0.100. Thanks for your help on the other one. I can use that masking technique for other things now! Much appreciated! :)